# PFSense пропадает инет каждый час на пару сек

Tags: pfsense

Имею **PFSense 2.3.2-RELEASE**

Каждые час в 15 минут вижу следующий лог:

`sonewconn: pcb 0xfffff80119f02ab8: Listen queue overflow: 193 already in queue awaiting acceptance (3317 occurrences)`

в этот момент пропадает инет у всех пользователей буквально на 10-15 сек

**netstan -Lan**

```
Proto Listen         Local Address
tcp4  0/0/128        127.0.0.1.3128
tcp4  0/0/128        192.168.100.250.3128
tcp6  0/0/128        *.80
tcp4  0/0/128        *.80
tcp4  0/0/128        *.22
tcp6  0/0/128        *.22
Netgraph sockets
Type  Recv-Q Send-Q Node Address   #Hooks
ctrl       0      0 [6]:              0
unix  0/0/5          /var/run/dpinger_WAN2GW~*******~77.88.8.1.sock
unix  0/0/5          /var/run/dpinger_WANGW~*******~77.88.8.8.sock
unix  0/0/4          /var/run/devd.pipe
unix  0/0/30         /var/run/check_reload_status
unix  0/0/128        /var/run/php-fpm.socket
unix  0/0/4          /var/run/devd.seqpacket.pipe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная ошибка в моем случае была связанна с настройками squid cache... Когда я поигрался, проблема исчезла. У кого та же проблема, копайте в этом направлении.

Comment: Опишите подробней